# Getting 404 Not Found in ngnix ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm facing issues with my Kubernetes Ingress configuration when trying to route different paths to different backend services under the same domain. The setup involves using NGINX Ingress Controller and regular expressions for path matching. I have multiple backend services (identity-api, pets-api, bookings-api, etc.) that should be accessible under the same domain (test.something.io) but with different paths. Here's my Ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "http://localhost:3000, http://localhost, http://localhost:4200"
  name: domigo-qa-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.something.io
      secretName: domigo-qaa
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: test.something.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /identity/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: identity-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /pets/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: pets-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /bookings/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: bookings-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /transaction/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: transaction-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /mediastorage/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mediastorage-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /facilities/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: facilities-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /summercamp/(.+)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: summercamp-api
                port:
                  number: 80
```

[image]

Though it is working when I use one path like below when I add something to the path it is not working I have checked the service and it is fine
but i want for all service in single domain

```
- host: test.something.io
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: identity-api
            port:
              number: 80
```